# Thinking Sphinx - multiple field conditions within scope

Tags: thinking-sphinx

Using thinking-sphinx 3.2.0.

I have scopes chained conditionally and would like to trigger ".search_for_ids" after chain is defined. Therefore, I would like to use a sphinx_scope to define conditions on multiple fields.

```
sphinx_scope(:for_query) do |query|
  {
    conditions: { title: query, description: query }
  }
end
```

This results in the following SphinxQL (excerpt):

```
WHERE MATCH('@title string @description string')
```

But I would like it to result in

```
WHERE MATCH('@title string | @description string')
```

Is this possible within a scope? or should I resign myself and let go the scope chaining and define it as a literal string params to .search?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, seem to have found the answer myself.

```
sphinx_search(:for_query) do |query|
  {
    conditions: { "(title,description)" => query }
  }
end
```

which results in

```
WHERE MATCH('@(title,description) string')
```

Thanks Pat and contributors for great gem!